# Нужно найти замену метода HasVertexAttribute(Rendering.VertexAttribute attr) на идентичный но который есть в версии unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
Mesh sharedMesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
 
if(!sharedMesh.HasVertexAttribute(VertexAttribute.TexCoord3))
    hasUV3 = false;
```

заранее прошу прощение если вопрос глупый я нуб в Unity и
переношу инструмент из проект unity 2019 в unity 2018

Comment: Из более нового в более старый? Не могу придумать ни одной причины это делать.